# How to test if the argument of the function is a string or an object

Tags: r, function

In an R function, I would like to give the possibility to users to choose an argument in the form of strings and without strings

How to test if the argument of the function is a string or an object ?

Many thanks in advance

```
library(rlang)

myfunction <- function(var) {
  
  if (is_string(var) == TRUE) {
    result <- var
  } else {
    result <- enquo(codgeo)
  }
  
  return(result)
}

myfunction("depcom") # return "depcom"
myfunction(depcom) # Error in is_string(var) : objet 'depcom'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support generic expressions in `var` you need to quote it before using it.
A function that can check this is:

```
is_string2 <- function(var) {
  enquo(var) %>% quo_get_expr() %>% is_string()
}
```

and something similar to what you wrote (but that returns a consistent type, you can drop the final as_string otherwise) is:

```
myfunction <- function(var) {
  enquo(var) %>% quo_get_expr() %>% as_string()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could check whether the input argument is quoted or not and use that information. There might be a ready-made function for that already, but you could also define it yourself, for example doing something like this:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

myfunction <- function(var, x=mtcars) {
    if(grepl('^["|\"]' , deparse(substitute(var)))) x[[var]] else 
        pull(x, !!enquo(var))
}

myfunction("disp")
#>  [1] 160.0 160.0 108.0 258.0 360.0 225.0 360.0 146.7 140.8 167.6 167.6 275.8
#> [13] 275.8 275.8 472.0 460.0 440.0  78.7  75.7  71.1 120.1 318.0 304.0 350.0
#> [25] 400.0  79.0 120.3  95.1 351.0 145.0 301.0 121.0
myfunction(disp)
#>  [1] 160.0 160.0 108.0 258.0 360.0 225.0 360.0 146.7 140.8 167.6 167.6 275.8
#> [13] 275.8 275.8 472.0 460.0 440.0  78.7  75.7  71.1 120.1 318.0 304.0 350.0
#> [25] 400.0  79.0 120.3  95.1 351.0 145.0 301.0 121.0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks ! I'm looking for the ready-made function

Comment: Well, just make that function: `is_quoted <- function(x) grepl('^["|\"]' , deparse(substitute(x)))` ...

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably a bad idea.  You could do it like this:

```
myfunction <- function(var) {
  
  if (is.name(substitute(var))) {
    result <- enquo(var)
  } else {
    result <- var
  }
  
  return(result)
}
```

but that won't work if someone wants to use an expression to produce a name, or a variable to produce a character value.  It's confusing to users when what they get depends on exactly how they expressed something.

A better approach is to use two arguments:  one that accepts characters, and one that accepts names.  Test which is not missing and declare an error if both are non-missing to decide what to do.  You could instead include another argument that tells the function how `var` should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

That works for me :

```
essai <- function(table=NULL) {
  
  if (is.name(substitute(table))) {
    result <- head(table)
  } else {
    result <- head(get(table))
  }
  
  print(result)
  
}

essai(table="iris")
essai(table=iris)
```